# Eslint config unallow semi

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have a trouble with eslint. In config for my node project that semi is not necessary, but some member still use it. 
How to show error when someone end line with semicolon?

Many thanks!

Comment: I found the solution, config .eslintrc with rule: `{..."semi": ["error", "never"],}`

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi - “never”

Comment: what is your ide ?